# Serve Different File with same URL

Tags: asp.net, .net

Using ASP.Net is it possible to have the application reference a file from a static location (ie. /Images/logo.png) but depending which user is logged it we will show the correct picture? We want to do this for a JSON file as well. We want to offload as much logic on the client/javascript end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If it's an MVC app**, then instead of linking to  /Images/logo.png, you could link to an MVC action that returns the image based on input parameter.

```
public ActionResult ProfileImage(string id)
{
    var dir = Server.MapPath("/Images");
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, id + ".png"); // validate the id parameter to make sure the final path is secure
    return base.File(path, "image/png");
}
```

Then you request image through the controller, eg.

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ProfileImage", "MyController", new { id = 12345 })" />
```

Which should output the following html:

```
<img src="MyController/ProfileImage?id=12345" />
```

**For an aspx type project,** use this in a ProfileImage.aspx file:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename=\"{0}.png\"", Request("id") ));
Response.ContentType = @"image/png";
Response.WriteFile(path);
```

Then add image tag :

```
<img src="ProfileImage.aspx?id=12345" />
```

**Note:**
That was the easy way. Ideally, you should remove all "id" parameters and use some kind of user session to retreive the user-id from server-side instead of passing it from the client.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do.. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess not, File Name is primary key for images. But if you are validating your user than u can surely pass default image in response from backend.